# Specific centering of text in the frame - beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations

I would like to put the following text in the center of the page with uppercase. How can I do this?

Thankful !

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}  
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}

\Huge Thank you !

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To vertically center the contents, use `c` as optional argument for the corrensponding frame. To also horizontally center your contents, use `\centering`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}  

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]{}

\centering \Huge Thank you !

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent @Leandriis, thank you very much !

Comment: @VeltonSousa: Since this answer seems to have solved your issue, please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). This way, it will be removed from the list of unanswered questions.